# Script to tile images not initialized until you resize the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page this is supposed to tile images like this

[image]

But when you first land on the page you see all the images stack behind each other

[image]

If you resize the browser at all it will shift everything into position. This is where I am at on the jQuery that makes this happen

### jQuery

```
var colCount = 0;
var colWidth = 300;
var margin = 10;
var spaceLeft = 0;
var windowWidth = 0;
var blocks = [];

$(function(){
  $(window).resize(setupBlocks);
});

function setupBlocks() {
  windowWidth = $(window).width();
  blocks = [];

  // Calculate the margin so the blocks are evenly spaced within the window
  colCount = Math.floor(windowWidth/(colWidth+margin*2));
  spaceLeft = (windowWidth - ((colWidth*colCount)+(margin*(colCount-1)))) / 2;
  console.log(spaceLeft);
  
  for(var i=0;i<colCount;i++){
    blocks.push(margin);
  }
  positionBlocks();
}

function positionBlocks() {
  $('.block').each(function(i){
    var min = Array.min(blocks);
    var index = $.inArray(min, blocks);
    var leftPos = margin+(index*(colWidth+margin));
    $(this).css({
      'left':(leftPos+spaceLeft)+'px',
      'top':min+'px'
    });
    blocks[index] = min+$(this).outerHeight()+margin;
  }); 
}

// Function to get the Min value in Array
Array.min = function(array) {
    return Math.min.apply(Math, array);
};
```

I think there must be something that I am not properly wrapping.

In the HTML I have this on my `<body>`

### HTML

```
<body onload="setupBlocks();">
```

My guess is that the line causing the problem is this

```
$(function(){
  $(window).resize(setupBlocks);
});
```

I would just google that but I don't know what that is called in there to see my other options. Can you just help me figure out this gap in information.

EDIT: the tutorial that I got this from works fine because he had all of his items hand coded. But in my projects all are being loaded into a mustache template.

So though I could get my script to load `onload` I guess, how would I get it to fire off both on load, and then again when resized?

Comment: @humble.rumble if I understood you correctly (which i don't think i did), the solution (or my implementation did not work) this is how I structured that block. http://pastebin.com/8HLgCD0i

Comment: @humble.rumble sorry but this is new to me. did you mean to remove onload from the HTML doc or from the method that i showed on pastebin? I tried both. Neither worked but likely since I might have added something in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `setupBlocks` function after page is loaded:

```
$(function(){
    setupBlocks();
    $(window).resize(setupBlocks);
});
```

Edit:

Looking at your html page, it looks like you are creating elements dynamically after the page is loaded. Try to update this code in your html page:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('img.js', function(data) {
        var template = $('#imgtpl').html();
        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
        $('#image-list').html(html);
        setupBlocks();
    });
});
```

Comment: It looks like you are creating elements dynamically. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Oh wow I was looking the the wrong place then. Yes your answer is totally correct.